# Ucchista and its rules- when, how, what?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras, food, smriti

When one eats food from a few vessels, the food as well as those vessels become Ucchista (उच्छिष्ट) (the food and hand touch the mouth, the same used hand touches those vessels to take new food from it). There are some who consider the surrounding area ucchista as well. Some even consider touching the vessel (e.g. glass) to the mouth as making the hand Ucchista and unfit for puja, although held from the other side. Regarding this concept, there are a few sub-questions.

1. When does something become Ucchista and what becomes? Is it by putting something in the mouth, touching the hand to the mouth or even touching something like a glass or spoon to the mouth makes the hand ucchista (glass will obviously become I’m asking about the hand).? Is ucchista restricted to eating drinking (since we wash our mouths after doing so) or does anything where saliva falls become ucchista?
2. How is Ucchista purified? In olden days they used to wash vessels with mud and nimboo but hands with water. Nowadays households use water and detergent. So if we use water as an alternative, can the energies create by someone’s ucchista be gotten ride off on the hand, vessel and surrounding area? What other alternatives are there? If someone touches someone with an ucchista hand how is that purified?
3. How must leftover ucchista food be treated so that nothing else become Ucchista. As in if we leave it for the dog, that area too will become ucchista. So...
4. Who all are allowed to eat one’s ucchista? Logically since everything for husband and wife is intertwined, since they engage in loving each other, they would be allowed each other’s ucchista. Besides them, who else is allowed and the logic behind it?
5. What are the acts forbidden when something is ucchista? Shraaddha, puja, touching someone else. Is there any ashaucha?

---

Please don’t write a partial answer for point 4. I’m aware some acharyas have listed some people who can eat ucchista. However I’d prefer a complete answer and better sourced from scriptures. Acharyas are always
Welcome just don’t write a partial answer to  point 4 quoting from existing works.

Comment: The food in a vessel(prepared in common) , never gets in touch with  mouth of any person at any cost .In this context, If the food is partaken in as seperate platter, leftover food in the vessel is avasistaअवशिष्ट, but the leftover food in the platter is ucchishta. If the food in the vessel itself becomes ucchishta, it is beyond the scope of any aachara practices

Comment: About 4th question - _they (Husband & Wife) would be allowed each other’s ucchista._ I think, that is not the case. I have read in some texts (can't recall) that only a wife must eat her husband's leftovers. A husband eating a wife's leftovers is sinful and forbidden. In some or other smriti or Purana.